# MySql INNER JOIN if select value bigger than 0

Tags: mysql

I'm having the following issue, I want to make a query which would return my table plan info.It looks similar like this:

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
| logs_id | plan_id | workout_id | plan_day | date_made           | workout_names_id | name         | language | workout_id | plan_names_id | name      | language_id | plan_id |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
|       2 |       1 |          1 |        1 | 2017-04-30 11:40:48 |                2 | Workout GR 1 |        2 |          1 |             2 | Plan 1 GR |           2 |       1 |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My problem is when there is no value for plan_id i get nothing,how can i get make a query which would return me some data even if the plan_id is 0.
Here is my code that i have made till now:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_logs(IN _language SMALLINT(255))
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM logs AS lo INNER JOIN workout_names AS wn ON lo.workout_id = wn.workout_id INNER JOIN plan_names AS pn ON lo.plan_id = pn.plan_id WHERE wn.language = _language AND pn.language_id = _language ORDER BY lo.logs_id;

END$$
```

When there are no values in the plan_id it deosnt return me anything.

> UPDATED!!

This following code works for a portion of the problem:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_logs(IN _language SMALLINT(255))
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM logs AS lo INNER JOIN workout_names AS wn ON lo.workout_id = wn.workout_id LEFT JOIN plan_names AS pn ON lo.plan_id = pn.plan_id WHERE wn.language = _language AND pn.language_id = _language ORDER BY lo.logs_id;


END$$
```

How can i pn.language_id = _language do it if the value in pn.language_id is not null.I have triend pn.language_id = _language IS NOT NULL but it returns me this:

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
| logs_id | plan_id | workout_id | plan_day | date_made           | workout_names_id | name         | language | workout_id | plan_names_id | name      | language_id | plan_id |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
|       3 |       1 |          1 |        1 | 2017-04-30 12:20:47 |                1 | Workout EN 1 |        1 |          1 |             1 | Plan 1 EN |           1 |       1 |
|       3 |       1 |          1 |        1 | 2017-04-30 12:20:47 |                1 | Workout EN 1 |        1 |          1 |             2 | Plan 1 GR |           2 |       1 |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Basically it get's me all languages tho i parse only one ,and it doesn't return me the one which is NULL.But if i add IS NULL it returns this:

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+------+-------------+---------+
| logs_id | plan_id | workout_id | plan_day | date_made           | workout_names_id | name         | language | workout_id | plan_names_id | name | language_id | plan_id |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+------+-------------+---------+
|       1 |       0 |          1 |        0 | 2017-04-30 10:52:24 |                1 | Workout EN 1 |        1 |          1 |          NULL | NULL |        NULL |    NULL |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------+--------------+----------+------------+---------------+------+-------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can i combine them to work like one?

Comment: Why down votes?

Comment: Because your question is unclear.

Comment: Your query is anyway returning plan name as `name`, what else do you want?

Comment: The plan name and plan_id are optional,and i want to be able to make a query if there is no value for them.

Comment: Uhm, you're inner joining plan_names. So pn.name is already there. So instead of *, just explicitly select the fields you need.  And use a LEFT JOIN to plan_names if you expect plan_id to be NULL.

Comment: @Arslan.H replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` in your query and it will return the expected result.

Comment: I'm working on it thanks for the down votes :D

Comment: @DarshanMehta thanks,there is one more thing.If that value is not null i want to add in my WHERE pn.language_id = _language.When i add pn.language_id = _language IS NULL it works for data which has null in that field but when i add IS NOT NULL it doest the reverse.

Comment: @juergend is it explained better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is it!!!

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE get_logs(IN _language SMALLINT(255))
    BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM logs AS lo INNER JOIN workout_names AS wn ON lo.workout_id = wn.workout_id LEFT JOIN plan_names AS pn ON lo.plan_id = pn.plan_id AND pn.language_id = _language WHERE wn.language = _language ORDER BY lo.logs_id;


    END$$
```